# Laravel7 + Queue & Supervisor => Mails are not sent

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I am using Queue to send out an order confirmation asynchronous and not make the user wait for payment completion in the frontend.
This works fine when using `php artisan queue:work` - everything is processed as it should.

Now when I want to let supervisor handle the sending, the jobs fail consistently with the following exception:

> [2020-08-17 19:54:12] production.ERROR: Cannot send message without a sender address {"exception":"[object] (Swift_TransportException(code: 0): Cannot send message without a sender address at /var/www/backend/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:195)

This obviously states that there is no sender address configured in `.env`. However there is, as well as in `config/mail.php`. I assume that supervisor can not read the global `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS` in `.env` or has no access to `.env` but I am not certain how to achieve that.

This is my supervisor config (as instructed in [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#supervisor-configuration)):

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/backend/artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data
numprocs=2
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/backend/worker.log
stopwaitsecs=3600
```

I am using `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database`.
The server is running nginx on ubuntu.

I also already tried to let supervisor use `user=root` without success.
Did anyone experience something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a directory:

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
directory=/var/www/backend
command=php artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data
numprocs=2
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/backend/worker.log
stopwaitsecs=3600
```